# How to create and return an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm really new to object/class concepts and already having difficulties with applying them. Could please sombody explain/show only the method below how to create and return an array of Exam objects? I need to get a data from a textfile which is passed to the method. Thanks in advance! I'd really appreciate it!

```
public Exam(String firstName, String lastName, int ID, String examType, int score)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.ID = ID;
    this.examType = examType;
    this.score = score;
}

public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s)
{
         Exam[] arrayList = null;
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    int ID = 0;
    String examValue = "";
    int score = 0;

    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        if(s.hasNextLine())
        {
            firstName = s.next();
            lastName = s.next();
        }
        else if(s.hasNextInt())
        {
            ID = s.nextInt();
        }
        else if (s.hasNextLine())
        {
            examValue = s.nextLine();
        }
        else if (s.hasNextInt())
        {
            score = s.nextInt();
        }

    }

    arrayList = {firstName, lastName, ID, examValue, score};
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: Wh.at ha.ve yo.u tri.ed? (And whose idea was it to add a filter to comments blocking people from asking what you've tried...)

Comment: instead of an array use an actual `List<Exam> arrayList = new ArrayList<Exam>();` and call `arrayList.add(new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examvalue, score));` on each `while` iteration.

Comment: @chancea, thanks but I'm not allowed to use arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your input to be one exam per line and every line in this format:

```
firstName lastName ID examType score
```

So a possible input would be:

```
firstName lastName 1 examType 2
Chuck Norris 42 Roundhousekicking 100
Sponge Bob 43 Burgermaking 50
```

(Note, that the Scanner does not differentiate between a space and a line break but this won't matter as long as every line has the above format. Also I won't handle errors in the input and just let the Scanner throw an Exception if something goes wrong.)

As Joel Abraham pointed out, Arrays in Java are immutable in length and I assume that we don't know the final length (i.e. the count of exams) we have to process and return before reading them. For that reason it's the easiest approach to create a temporary ArrayList (which can adjust its length) and add as many Exams to it as the input contains (`while (s.hasNext())`).
To get the desired return value of the type `Exam[]` we have to convert this ArrayList back to an Array which is done by `anyNumberofExams.toArray(new Exam[0])`. It is some specialty of Java that we have to provide an Array of the type `Exam[]` and in this case length 0 to the `toArray` function so it knows which type the generated Array has to be.

Here is some working code and good luck with your exams!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exam {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exam[] exams = Exam.readAllExams(new Scanner(
                "Firstname Lastname 1 ExamType 2\n"
                + "Chuck Norris 42 Roundhousekicking 100\n"
                + "Sponge Bob 43 Burgermaking 50"));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(exams));
    }

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int ID;
    private String examType;
    private int score;

    public Exam(String firstName, String lastName, int ID, String examType, int score)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.examType = examType;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Exam: (firstName: %s, lastName: %s, ID: %d, " 
                +"examType: %s, score: %d)", 
                firstName, lastName, ID, examType, score);
    }

    public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s)
    {
        ArrayList<Exam> anyNumberofExams = new ArrayList<>();
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            anyNumberofExams.add(new Exam(s.next(), s.next(), s.nextInt(), 
                    s.next(), s.nextInt()));
        }
        return anyNumberofExams.toArray(new Exam[0]);
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Here is an example without ArrayList but I do not recommend it as it gets inefficient for many Exams and is less readable for someone who is used to ArrayLists.

```
public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s)
{
    Exam[] examsArray = new Exam[0];
    int count = 0;
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        Exam exam = new Exam(s.next(), s.next(), s.nextInt(), 
                s.next(), s.nextInt());
        Exam[] newArray = new Exam[count + 1];

        // copy old array to new array - this is very inefficient
        System.arraycopy(examsArray, 0, newArray, 0, examsArray.length);

        examsArray = newArray;
        examsArray[count] = exam;
        count++;
    }
    return examsArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do without arrayList? @dauer

Comment: @jordan Yes, it is possible without ArrayList but either you know the number of exams before reading and counting them or it gets ugly in my opinion. (It would result in writing some kind of rudimentary ArrayList yourself but Java's well written and well tested ArrayList does an excellent Job here.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with construction and manipulation of arrays, then you can ignore a large majority of the above code.

An array is a simply collection of items organized into a list. Arrays can contain any number and type of items, and can be multi-dimensional as well (in which you have an array of arrays, and more...).  While arrays are final and cannot be altered, an ArrayList is a mutable array (an array that can be changed).

This particular array is instantiated through the code:
     *Exam[] arrayList = null;*
with the name of the array being *"arrayList"*. It is initialized with a value of *null*, indicating that it is empty, however, it is filled later in the code with *arrayList = {firstName, lastName, ID, examValue, score};*. This designates the variable *firstName* to be at position 0 of the array, *lastName* at position 1, and so on. The final statement *return arrayList;* then returns the array.